# Access member of class from a constructor of another class

Tags: c++

My code looks something like this:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

int d,f;
A c();
d = c.GetStuff();

B *d = new C();
f = d->Get();

return 0;
}
```

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
class A
{
int a;

public A();

int GetStuff() {return(a) ;}

};

#endif
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

A::A()
{
 a = 42;//just some value for sake of illustration
}
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

Class B 
{
public:
virtual int Get(void) =0;

};

class C: public B {
public:
C();

int Get(void) {return(a);}
};
#endif
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

C::C() {
a // want to access this int a that occurs in A.cpp
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to gain access to "a" in B.cpp?
I tried using class "friend", but I am not getting results.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: There are a few flubs in your code, but it's not clear what you're trying to do.  What do you think the constructor for `A` is doing?

Comment: The full code is very long, I tried posting only the relevant structures, sorry if its confusing. The constructor for A in theory provides a value for "a", this value I want to be able to access in B.cpp

Comment: I see, I just fixed it a little. Hopefully now it makes sense.

Comment: @user1981855: There is no single `a` variable. It exists inside any instances of the `A` class, so if you want to access *an* `a` you need *an* instance of `A`.

Comment: This question isn't really possible to answer. Is there one instance of `A` and lots of instances of `B`? Or are `A` and `B` in one-to-one relationship. Does an `A` own a `B` or vice versa? Or are they completely de-coupled.

Comment: @David Heffernan: `A` only occurs once in main.cpp, `B` could occur more than once I suppose.  Right now, `A` and `B` have no relationship, but I need `B` to access `a` from `A`, if possible at all. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: did you mean `c().GetStuff()` ?

Comment: @user1981855 Regarding your statement "Right now, A and B have no relationship, but I need B to access a from A, if possible at all", without knowing what A and B are, it's pretty much impossible to suggest what the relationship *ought* to be.  There are countless ways to access variables (static class variables, global variables, dependency injection, inheritance, delegation, etc.) - I'm reluctant to suggest anything because it might be inappropriate for A and B and C, whatever they actually are.

Comment: @wilsonmichaelpatrick: I see, that makes sense. The operations of `A` are completely independent from `B` and `C`. But `C` needs the `a` value from `A`. Perhaps I should post the whole code, sorry for the mess.

Comment: @user I'm not sure that you've fully grasped the difference between a type and an instance. In order to solve this you have to start talking about instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different answers, depending on what you mean

If each A object is meant to have it's own unique 'a' variable (which is how you've defined it) then you'll need to pass an `A` into the constructor of `C`:

```
C::C(const A &anA) {
int foo= anA.a; // 
}
```

And, invoking the constructor becomes:

```
A myA;
B *myC = new C(myA);   // You picked confusing names for your classes and objects
```

However, if you intended all A objects to share a common `a` value, then you should declare `a` and `getStuff` as `static` in `A` :

```
class A
{
static int a;  
public:
static int GetStuff() {return a;};
```

... and access it as `A::GetStuff()` in the `C` constructor.

Comment: I see. Your first suggestion is what I need. What if I wanted constructor `C` to have access to all members of class `A`? Assuming class `A` has more objects.

Comment: *Assuming class A has more objects* What do you mean, and are you sure you understand the terminology you're using? `A` is a class, `A foo;` declares an instance of that class called `foo`, and `foo.a` is a member of that instance. `C` can access all public members of `A`. Making it a `friend` would allow it to access private ones as well.